# How to Add a row in a table and alternate row colors?

Tags: excel, vba

I wanna add a row at the end of my table and automaticaly alternate rows color. I have the code here but row is not added to the table but to the activesheet. I don't know how to properly loop through my rows in the table.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim lr As Long
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

    Rows(lr + 1).Insert

    Dim lrow As Excel.ListRow
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("WorkZone")

    For Each lrow In tbl.ListRows

        If Cells.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) And Cells.row Mod 2 = 0 Then

            Cells.Interior.Color = RGB(242, 242, 242)

        End If

    Next lrow

End Sub
```

Comment: For adding a row to a table look at this https://www.bluepecantraining.com/portfolio/excel-vba-how-to-add-rows-and-columns-to-excel-table-with-vba-macro/

Comment: With this code (that I have already try) I get this message : macro run-time error '9': subscript out of range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub AlternateRows()
    Dim lst As ListObject, lstRow As ListRow
    Set lst = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
    lst.ListRows.Add '//Add row
    For Each lstRow In lst.ListRows
        lstRow.Range.Interior.Color = _
            IIf(lstRow.Index Mod 2 = 0, vbRed, vbGreen) '//Color rows
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a `For Each` loop, I would recommend looping on an index because it's more obvious to see which row you are updating.

By specifying **just** `.Cells`, you're specifying all of the cells in the sheet! To fix that, I would normally recommend changing it it `.cells( <row>, <column> ).Interior ...`, but since you're actually only looking at a row within the table, you can use `ListObects.ListRows( <row> )` to access certain rows within said table.

I also changed the way that you were adding the row to the end of the table because to me it makes more sense to use the built in [`ListRows.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listrows.add) function since, like above, you really just want to access the table and not the whole sheet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("WorkZone")

    tbl.ListRows.Add (tbl.ListRows.count + 1)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To tbl.ListRows.count
        With tbl.ListRows(i).Range
            If i Mod 2 <> 0 Then
                .Interior.color = RGB(242, 242, 242)
            End If
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I get this error message: Subscript out of range (Error 9)

Comment: @MaxBridge on what line? is it the `.Add` line?

Comment: Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("WorkZone")

Comment: @MaxBridge but I copied that right from your code! Did you rename your table to not be "WorkZone" anymore?

Comment: This error means that your ActiveSheet doesn't have a table called "WorkZone". Check the table names or make sure you are on the correct sheet. Better use `Worksheets("SheetName").ListObjects("WorkZone")` and avoid using `ActiveSheet`

Comment: @MaxBridge you could also try replacing `"ListObjects("WorkZone")` with `ListObjects(1)`. Not a guaranteed fix but might work

Comment: Ok sorry I fix the correct table name. Adding a row is working perfectly. but the new row is always gray (RGB 242,242,242)

Comment: @MaxBridge is your goal to remove the coloring then? I'm working with what you gave me

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Sorry English is not my first language. I want every added row to be gray if the row number is odd. hope I'm clear

Comment: @MaxBridge do you want it to check based on the row number within the table or the row number on the left side of the screen?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Whatever! just  alternate one row white one row gray

Comment: @MaxBridge okay I changed it, give it a try

Comment: I manipulated with ListObject object model rather range directly. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52042934/3187033). :)

Comment: @JohnyL I like yours better tbh, I'm the one who voted it up :)

Comment: Oh!... *~blushing~* :)